# how to configure xorg.conf for extended desktop?

Tags: xorg, multi-monitor, ati

I would like to setup the dual monitor settings where I can use two monitors as a single Desktop with single panel, single launcher and when some programs are maximized then it should span both the monitors (i.e fullscreen over both the monitors).

I have ATI Raedon graphics cards and after searching it in the internet I found that by configuring the xorg.conf file I can setup the settings that I want.

I have tried several ways to do it i.e

```
using gksu amdcccle
```

And setting MultiDisplay settings, but my requirement has not yet been met. ***NOTE:*** I have done this using Nvidia graphics but its seem that it doesn't work with ATI graphics card.

After searching for a while I found the link which gave me hope that it can be done in ATI as well, According to this [link](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?18553-Ubuntu-9-04-amp-Catalyst-9-7-%28fglrx%29).

xrandr must be disabled and AMD catalyst center will give the extra option of Big Desktop, to set it I used

```
sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-str="DDX,EnableRandR12,FALSE"
```

Then I restart X as per that [link](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?18553-Ubuntu-9-04-amp-Catalyst-9-7-%28fglrx%29).

But this command gives this output to the stdout:

> SetPcsStr is exclusive, other options will not be used.

And I didn't find any extra configuration in my `xorg.conf` file.

And I didn't even get the Big Desktop option in the AMD Catalyst center's Display manager. There is still three options i.e:

```
Single Desktop
Cloned Display
Multiple Display
```

Comment: What desktop environment and window manager?  Some of these things depend on window manager support in particular.

Comment: You need to enable "eyefinity" for the ATI driver to make this work afaik.

Comment: 2013 called and it wanted its question back. There should be a smarter algorithm applied to bumping to the homepage. And honestly, there should be very little bumping on U.SE as the vast majority of questions with unaccepted answers is due to two things: 1) they are throw-away single-use questions, and 2) the downvoter trolls got to the OP and he/she is not coming back. One size (the same bumping algorithm) does not fit  all SEs.

Answer (score 1):

Look for Xinerama X11 feature :

- [Tutorial with ATI section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XineramaHowTo)
- [General information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinerama)

Comment: Thank you @GHugo for the helpful links, those links helped me to learn more about Xinerama. But I could make the Xinerama to work only with Nvidia graphics card, I am not able to do this with ATI Radeon graphics card

Comment: In the first on there is an xorg.conf for ati. Do you have any error ?

Comment: Yes GHugo I tried the xorg.conf file as per the first link, But it didnot work as it did with Nvidia, fullscreen was spanning over one monitor , but I want the applications to be fullscreen over both the monitors, I want to use both the monitors as a big monitor, I did this with Twinview setup and Xinerama in Nvidia but with ATI I am really confused why Xinerama is not working as per definitions..